# PUT method not supported for the route when trying to do an update method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

This is what my code looks like

Route:

```
Route::put('/articles/{$article}', 'ArticlesController@update');
```

Controller:

```
 public function update($id){

        $article=Article::find($id);

        $article ->title = request('title');
        $article->excerpt=request('excerpt');
        $article->body=request('body');

        $article->save();

        return redirect('/articles/'. $article->id);


    }
```

Blade:

```
 <form method="POST" action="/articles/{{$article->id}}" >
                @csrf
                @method('PUT')
```

And everytime I try to submit an update I get this:

```
The PATCH method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
```

I'm currently stuck on this one.

Comment: please share all routes related to `articles`. are you using resource() for routes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<form action="/articles/{{$article->id}}" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

and the route

```
Route::put('/articles/{article}', 'ArticlesController@update');
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't notice I had a $ in the route. My bad

Answer (score 1):

It's better to do:

- in routing

```php
Route::put('/articles/{id}', 'ArticlesController@update')->name('articles.update');
```

- in controller

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
   // logic
}
```

> don't forget to use Request in controller

- in blade

it's better to use naming for routes but it might be a problem in your action

```php
   <form method="POST" action="{{ route('articles.update', $article->id) }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

simple way using blade

```
<form action="/articles/{{$article->id}}" method="POST">
 @method('put')
 @csrf
</form>
```